# JS HTML: call random function from array

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to call a function that I got randomly from an array. Here is the link:https://codepen.io/Dims09/pen/poRrKWP

Right now I have the following code:
JS

```
const areoT = document.getElementById("for");

function getValue() {
  var randoRandit = [na(), na2(), na3(), na4()];
  var rand = randoRandit[Math.floor(Math.random() * randoRandit.length)];
  // alert(rand)
  // document.getElementById("for").innerHTML=rand;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="for"></div>
<button id="J?2e" onclick="getValue()">CF</button>
```

What Im wondering Is how to call it once gotten random item.
I’ve tried `eval()`, `window[]()`, and even `rand()` .
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Modern JS basics: don't use HTML attributes to trigger JS. In your JS, add `yourbtnid.addEventListener("click", evt => getValue(evt));`, and modern HTML basics: don't put question marks in `id` attributes. Whatever taught you HTML and Js is a bad tutorial/site/book, and even for your own skill/sanity you want to revisit modern JS and HTML by hitting up some properly modern tutorials (e.g. written in the last year specific to HTML5 and ES6, but ideally ES2020)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I was not taught to do onclick in my HTML for the reason that addEventListener is much better. The reason I don't use addEventListener is stated in my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031124/javascript-html-addeventlistener-not-working?noredirect=1#comment118484846_67031124 post

Answer (score 2):

You need to store just the function references (without the `()`) in the array then use `rand()` to call the returned function

```js
function na() {
  console.log('na() called');
  return 'na'
}

function na2() {
  console.log('na2() called');
  return 'na2'
}

function na3() {
  console.log('na3() called');
  return 'na3'
}
// array of the function references
var randoRandit = [na, na2, na3];
var rand = randoRandit[Math.floor(Math.random() * randoRandit.length)];
// now call the function
var result = rand();
document.querySelector('div').textContent = result
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you must take in account that every time you write an identifier followed by a parenthesized list of parameters (even if it is empty), you **are** calling a function.

So, in this line:

```
var randoRandit = [na(), na2(), na3(), na4()];
```

... you are calling **four** functions and then storing the returned values as items into an array. Is this what you realy want? I guess no.

If you want to reference a function without actually calling it, it is enough to write its name (without parenthesis):

```
// Declaration:
function myFunction() {...}

// Referenciation:
var f=myFunction;
// Now f acts as a reference to your real function.

// Calling:
f(...)
```